# Ruby: values of constants

Tags: ruby

I'm using

```
MyModule.constants.each do |c|
  #my loop
end
```

How do I get the VALUE of each constant rather than its name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for [`Module#const_get`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000485):

```
irb(main):014:0> MyModule.constants.each do |c|
irb(main):015:1*   puts(c.to_s + "  " + MyModule.const_get(c).to_s)
irb(main):016:1> end
MY_CONST  5
=> [:MY_CONST]
```

Answer (score 5):

See [`Module.const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000485):

```
module MyModule
  FOO = 42
  BAR = 17
end
MyModule.constants.each do |c|
  p [ c, MyModule.const_get(c) ]
end
#=> [:FOO, 42]
#=> [:BAR, 17]
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `Module::constants` and `Module#constants` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
map = {}
MyModule.constants.each do |name|
  map[name] = MyModule.const_get(name)
end
```